# Указание пути к файлу в браузере

Tags: python

Подскажите. Как указать путь к файлу на Mac OS на python в интерпретаторе, который открыт в браузере. И вообще можно так делать?

На просторах интернета так ответа и не нашел(

Comment: если можно, то можете объяснить с наглядным примером

Comment: Вы открыли online python? Если да, то при чём тут Mac OS - скрипт выполняется на удалённом сервере. Смотрите на этом сайте, как файлы открывать и какие там пути

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.